# Problema en Debian 10 buster y Atom

Tags: debian, atom-editor

Bien, recién instalé **Debian** **10** y todo bien hasta aquí, el problema es que al intentar abrir `Atom` desde root me aparece el siguiente error:

> No protocol specified
>   (atom:24721): Gtk-WARNING **://fecha: cannot open display: :0

Ya intenté con [esto](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118811/why-cant-i-run-gui-apps-from-root-no-protocol-specified) pero no conseguí solucionarlo.

¿Alguien tuvo el mismo problema?

PD: Abrir Atom desde mi usuario no hay problema, solo en el root.

Comment: Si es para editar algún fichero de configuración del sistema y necesitas root, es más sencillo usar otro editor y ya. Yo uso `nano` y edito en el mismo terminal en esos casos. No se me ocurre otra razón por la que necesitar abrir Atom como root. Pero eres libre de hacerlo, claro jaja.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que tu sesión X pertenece a ti y ningun otro usuario, incluso root, no tiene derecho de conectarse. La pregunta mas relevante es porque estas intentando abrir un editor de código como root! Esto ya indica que algo va mal.

Te recomiendo arreglar tus ficheros y sus permisos para que no necesites nunca hacer algo así como root.

Si insistes, la solución es dar derechos a otros usuarios conectarse a tu sesión. Asumiendo que solo eres tu quien trabaja con esa maquina, puedes simplemente hacer:

```
xhost +
```

Después, ya puedes abrir Atom como root. Una vez has acabado, vuelve a cerrar con:

```
xhost -
```

Pero en serio. No lo hagas. Mira porque necesitas hacerlo como root y cámbialo. A lo peor, usa `sudo`.